# Using Cauchy product for an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation, cauchy-product

To evaluate
$$
\int_0^1 e^x \ln(x+1)dx
$$
I was thinking about using the cauchy product of the taylor series of $e^x$ and $\ln(x+1)$. We know that
$$ 
e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
and
$$
\ln(x+1) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m+1}x^m}{m}
$$
So using:
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty b_m x^m \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^n (a_m b_{n-m}) x^n
$$
We have:
$$
\int_0^1 e^x \ln(x+1)dx = \int_0^1  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^n \left(\frac{(-1)^{1 + n - m}}{m\cdot m!} b_{n-m}\right) x^n dx
$$
I switch the integration and summation bounds but I do not know how to justify this:
$$
\int_0^1 e^x \ln(x+1)dx =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^n \left(\frac{(-1)^{1 + n - m}}{(n-m)\cdot m!}\right) \int_0^1 x^n dx
$$
Obtaining:
$$
\int_0^1 e^x \ln(x+1)dx =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^n \left(\frac{(-1)^{1 + n - m}}{(n-m)(n+1)\cdot m!} \right)
$$
I tried to plug this into desmos but it does not work.

Comment: Its undefined because of $m=0$ in the original series

Comment: @NinadMunshi Can I just let $m$ start at $1$? Or is the series just not convergent?

Comment: No you can do that, but you'll have to start over because the double sum will be slightly different when they start at different points.

Answer (score 2):

Your integral is

$$ \int_0^1 e^x \ln(x+1) dx=e\ln(2)-\int_0^1 \dfrac{e^x}{x+1}dx=e\ln(2)-\int_1^2e^{-1}\dfrac{e^u}{u}du$$

Which is  $$ e\ln(2)-e^1 (Ei(1)-Ei(2))$$

Where $Ei$ is the exponential integral :

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html